# what is the nominative for кутасы (and what does it mean)

Tags: значения, существительные

I believe the nominative form of **кутасы** will be **кутаса**?

What does **кутаса** mean?

I found this word in the following sentence, which I took from 
Война и мир (Толстой)/Том I/Часть II/Глава VII:

Поглядев на мост, он видел столь же однообразные живые волны солдат, **кутасы**, 
кивера с чехлами, ранцы, штыки, длинные ружья и из-под киверов лица с широкими скулами,
ввалившимися щеками и беззаботно-усталыми выражениями и движущиеся ноги по натасканной
на доски моста липкой грязи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словарь Ефремовой: [Кутáс - м. Шнур с кистью на кивере](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/180087)

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: found this detailed explanation with pictures, starting from your second link: http://saper.isnet.ru/uniform/uniform-5a.html